# gganimate won't render when combining geom_point and geom_sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, gganimate

I'm trying to animate points moving over a map in gganimate. In teh following example, animating just the points works and a static plot of the points and map works, but combining them fails with the error `Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length`

Here's a repro:

#### Load libraries

```
# gganimate isn't on CRAN
devtools::install_github('thomasp85/gganimate')
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
library(sf)
# for the spatial data
library(rnaturalearth)
```

#### Create data

```
# Points data
time <- seq(ISOdate(2015, 6, 1), ISOdate(2015, 8, 1), length.out = 100)
track1 <- tibble(lon = seq(-161, -155, length.out = 100),
                 lat = seq(19, 25, length.out = 100),
                 time = time,
                 trackid = 1)
track2 <- tibble(lon = seq(-155, -161, length.out = 100),
                 lat = seq(19, 25, length.out = 100),
                 time = time,
                 trackid = 2)
d <- rbind(track1, track2)

# Spatial data
earth <- st_as_sf(ne_download(scale = "medium",
                              category = "physical",
                              type = "coastline"))
deg_buff <- 1
lon_range <- range(d$lon) + c(-deg_buff, deg_buff)
lat_range <- range(d$lat) + c(-deg_buff, deg_buff)
bbox <- st_polygon(list(cbind(lon_range[c(1,1,2,2,1)], 
                              lat_range[c(1,2,2,1,1)])))
bbox <- st_sfc(bbox)
st_crs(bbox) <- st_crs(earth)
area <- st_intersection(earth, bbox)
```

#### Animate points (works)

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(lon, lat)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = 'Date: {format(frame_time, "%b %e")}') +
  transition_components(trackid, time) +
  shadow_trail(distance = 0.01, size = 0.3)
animate(p, 100, 20)
```

#### Plot a static map (works)

```
ggplot(d, aes(lon, lat)) +
  geom_sf(data = area, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_point()
```

#### Animate points with static map in background (fails)

```
p2 <- ggplot(d, aes(lon, lat)) +
  geom_sf(data = area, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = 'Date: {format(frame_time, "%b %e")}') +
  transition_components(trackid, time) +
  shadow_trail(distance = 0.01, size = 0.3)
animate(p2, 100, 20)
```

Comment: gganimate is not on cran, otherwise a great MWE. Could you add a comment with the devtools::install code? Just as speculation, where do the arguments to transitions_components come from? It seems you would need an sf object with a time series of centering points.

Comment: @RichardCareaga Totally forgot gganimate isn't on CRAN - thanks for the reminder! I think the arguments to transition_components are similar to arguments to aes, that is unquoted column names. In transition_components, they're the grouping and timestep variables, respectively. But I don't want the geom_sf to animate. I just want it there in the background. Not sure how to indicate it should be a static layer.

Answer (score 2):

[image: 1]

1. Moved `data = d` and `aes()` from `ggplot()` to `geom_point()`
2. Changed `transition_components()` to `transition_time()`
3. Changed `shadow_trail` to `shadow_wake`
4. (Added color)

#### Code

```
p2 <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = area, color = "red") +
    geom_point(data = d, aes(lon, lat), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    labs(subtitle = 'Date: {format(frame_time, "%b %e")}') +
    transition_time(time) +
    shadow_wake(0.3)

animate(p2, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

*trackid* is undefined and what throws the error in p2; *time* is defined.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. ```trackid``` is defined in ```d```. It's 1 for the first 100 rows and 2 for the second 100 rows. It's undefined in ```area```, but then again so is ```time```.

Comment: Added an answer, b/c that's the only way I've found to do code blocks. When running the example *time* ends up in the namespace because it's globally defined, but *trackid* doesn't; it's local to the *d*, *track1* and *track2* objects. You do call *d* in the initial ggplot() for p2, but then for geom_sf, you use area as the data. d is a tibble and if you want to refer to it's components, you either have to do it explicitly, as in d$trackid or through %>% when you can use the bare name.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. ```transition_components``` takes unquoted column names just like ```aes``` in ```ggplot```. Also, if it was a matter of ```trackid``` being undefined then the first animated plot wouldn't work, but this does: 
    p <- ggplot(d, aes(lon, lat)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(subtitle = 'Date: {format(frame_time, "%b %e")}') +
      transition_components(trackid, time) +
      shadow_trail(distance = 0.01, size = 0.3)
    animate(p, 100, 20)

Comment: d in the first animation works because it sets the data and the + arguments don't change it, so there's no need to quote "tracked." "Time" is already global.